# Organizing External Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, html

I recently stated to wonder what is the best way to organize JavaScript files.

Example:

Let's say I have an HTML with input fields. I want to validate those fields before they are submitted.

Where do I call these type of functions `document.getElementById()`? In the external JavaScript file or in the HTML inside a `script` tag and a listener when the content is ready?

```
index.html
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e){
        var field1 = document.getElementById('field1');
        var field2 = document.getElementById('field2');

        var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    });
</script>

<form method='post' action='some-url'>
    <input type='text' id='field1'/>
    <input type='text' id='field2'/>
    etc...
    <input type='submit' id='submit'/>
</form>
```

or something like the following

```
file.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e){
    var field1 = document.getElementById('field1');
    var field2 = document.getElementById('field2');

    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
});


index.html
<form method='post' action='some-url'>
    <input type='text' id='field1'/>
    <input type='text' id='field2'/>
    etc...
    <input type='submit' id='submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: The second example is the preferred approach. Try to keep your html and JS separate

Comment: @michael  Thank you all, I was curious because I have seen in many websites, this for instance where a script tag is put right inside head tags. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to have an external javascript file that is included to your html file at the end of the html's body.

```
<body>
    awesome html ... 
    <script src='/path/to/file.js'></script>
</body>
```

By loading the script at the end of the body you ensure that the elements are loaded and available in the DOM so that javascript can get them by Id or whatever.

If you want to improve your pages performance (and have a significant sized js file) you should consider to minify your javascript. You can do this with gulp, for example.

Comment: The more important reason why this is done (given that jquery is so common) is that javascript loading blocks all other assets from loading until the javascript is downloaded and executed. Loading JS last does not ACTUALLY load the page faster, but since it won't block images and CSS when it's at the bottom, it gives the APPEARANCE of loading faster to the end user.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, so once I separate the files and create some namespaces do I grab the elements inside the javascript file or in the script inside html. For instance I create a namespace and call it Namespace.init() should I call document.getElementById and attacth listeners inside namespace or pass the elements through Namespace.init(document.getElementById('some element'))
Thanks I hope I am being clear!

Comment: No, sorry I don't get it. ;) But as a simple rule, try to put all javascript in a js file whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

You should call those script after those html input fields. Usually JavaScript files are included at the end of html body. So that javascript can work on the body after it's loading. Though js has its own function to automatically run after loading the body but the standard is to include the js files at the bottom of the body.

An important important point to consider is: suppose you have used jquery and there is another js for slider. If the js of slider is written using jquery then you have to load your slider js file after loading the jquery files.

Answer (score 0):

Usual practice, javascript will be placed right before body tag and alternatively in case you wanna play/mess up with DOM always remember to use this .live in jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/live/